# How to fix [<br /> when trying to enter data through php in data (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm trying to add a graph to my data. This data is imported from phpmyadmin. The data goes through, i have the tables under it. When I try to add the data, I get an error because it translates my php to `[<br />`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [<?php echo $Timers; ?>],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Time',
            data: [<?php echo $Wheights; ?>],
```

the php

```
while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_array($records1)){

            $Timer = date('M, Y', strtotime($stelling['Timer']));
            $Wheight = $stelling['Wheight'];
            $Title = $stelling['Title'];

$Timers = '';
$Wheights = '';
$Titles = '';

$Timers = $Timers.'"'.$Timer.'",';
$Wheights = $Wheights.$Wheight.',';
$Titles = $Titles.$Title.',';

$Timers = trim($Timers, ",");
$Wheights = trim($Wheights, ",");
$Titles = trim($Titles, ",");



}include ("script/graph.php");
    }
```

This is the error:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [<br />
< etc
```

I expect the data to come through the chart.js to form a graph
[image: Here is the database]

Comment: Seems that `$Timers` is not defined and you are getting a notice

Comment: @ka_lin Thanks, yeh, its outside the function where it gets defined. I now tried to include it right before the bracket, but then it doesn't show at all. 
I tried this:
`$Timers = trim($Timers, ",");
$Wheights = trim($Wheights, ",");
$Titles = trim($Titles, ",");


include ("script/graph.php");
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems issue at your javascript code..it is not converting the php array to javascript properly.

**try this:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var labels = '<?php echo json_encode($Timers); ?>';

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Time',
            data: [<?php echo $Wheights; ?>],
```

Comment: I tried it, and i get the same problem: `var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var labels = '<br />`

Comment: Please share the values of `$Timers` variable.

Comment: I added a picture of the database to the question @Vikash Pathak

Comment: Thank you,  after some manipulation of the code, i implemented your code again and it shows itself in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`<br />` is part of php error, that doesn't show completely in rendered html.

if you want to see actual error, you can see page source (Ctrl+u).

Comment: this is what the console is saying: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (refering to the <)

Comment: @Thomas no, not the console. see the html of result. php error is commented out.

Comment: yes, you mean where there is the red cross in the source code of the html? because that says the same thing

Comment: @Thomas no, "Invalid or unexpected token" is js error. find php error in html source.

Comment: I think that's why I also don't get out of this problem. The php doesn't show any errors, Because my php errors should show automatically. At least, it has for my whole time working on this file. @yaya pro

Comment: @Thomas you should isolate your problem. remove all of your codes, just write `<?php echo $Timers; ?>` and see what will render. if nothing, usethis to enable php error reporting  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: Yes, I have done so. I added this line to the php and it prints it prints out: "Apr, 2019""Apr, 2019" as expected. The problem is that javascript does not recognize the variable although i included it in the function.

Comment: @Thomas i saw your updated question. you should change it back to <?php echo $Timers; ?>. you should share your full code. where is js located? in a .php file? how these two files connected to each other? currenlt your question is vague.

Comment: sorry, I rolled it back. I'm just running through a series of problems trying to show the data from the database to chart.js. But my question is answered. I no longer have the </br. It now shows the data when I echo it. but it doesn't yet properly show in the chart javascript because of the way it should be syntaxed. Thanks for your help!